# Problem with noisy relays

Tags: relay

I am doing a project right now that uses four SRD-5VDC relays. They switch power from an outlet to the rest of my project. Unfortunately they make a loud click every time they switch. Is there a quieter relay on the market or a transistor circuit that can handle 120V AC switching?

Comment: Mechanical relays click. Look for solid state relays.

Comment: Acoustic amplification is often due to the sounding board effect and is reduced by making them inline to cable. with heatshrink or layers of electrical tape.

Answer (score 2):

You may use solid state relays (SSR), them being the semiconductor equivalent of a relay. They usually switch AC mains voltage via low DC, usually 3V to 32V (it's almost always printed on their top faces, otherwise check their datasheet). There are also [circuits with opto-isolators and triacs](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/power44.gif) that achieve the same result.